# Uniqueness of charge distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, inverse-problems, electromagnetism

Some exercises in general physics ask for students to find specific charge distributions on the boundaries of given conductors in various of situations. Usual answers goes like follows; firstly using symmetries or other techniques, e.g. image charges, to 'guess' how the distribution looks like, and then completes solution testing the boundary conditions, vanishing electric fields, etc. Almost surely, a mathematically oriented one may suspect that other possibilities maybe possible. So this question is almost surely duplicated. So let me state precise questions in the following form.

**Question 0** Is question 1 duplicates or nonsense? If not, ignore question 0. If so please indicate the places where this question appeared or the reason it is trivially wrong or true.

**Question 1** Is the following statement is true:
*Let $V_e: \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function which vanishes at infinity uniformly. Let $C$ be a finite union of a collection of pairwise disjoint bounded domains say $C_1$, $C_2$, $\ldots$, $C_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose boundary $S$ is a union of smooth surfaces $S_1$, $S_2$, $\ldots$, $S_n$ which are mutually non-overlapping(that is for any $i \neq j$, $S_i \cap S_j$ has no interior in $S_i$ with respect to the induced topology on $S_i$). For each $j=1,2, \ldots , n$, let $Q_j$ be a real number which represents the total charge on $S_j$. Then there is unique surface distribution $\sigma$ on $S$ so that the potential 
$$V(y) = \int_S \frac{\sigma(x)}{\hbox{dist}(x,y)} dx + V_e(y) $$ is constant on each of connected component of $C$ where $\int_{S_j} \sigma (x) dx =Q_j$ for each $j=1,2, \ldots, n$*

Comment: I'm sorry, this is nearly incomprehensible.

Comment: Related, I've never seen the mathematical proof that conductors can reach statics (i.e. the proof that conductors eventually reach $0$ net electric field inside when you apply an external field to it). To do so, you would have to prove for _every_ external field $\vec{E}_{\text{ext}}$ and _every_ arbitrary conductor with surface $S$, there exists a surface charge configuration such that $\int_S \frac{\sigma(S)}{\text{dist}^2(S,y)}\hat{u}\; dS = - \vec{E}_{\text{ext}}$ for all points $y$ in the conductor, and that the surface current $\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{v}$ is $0$(velocity is 0 statics)

Comment: The fact that conductors can do this, any conductor, is remarkable/magical. But I haven't seen mathematical proof of it. Nor have I ever seen the proof that the electric field, when it hits a surface charge, undergoes a discontinuity in it's normal component. This proof would require real analysis in a multivariable setting. I don't even think most physicists have seen this prooft

Comment: Also, any "proof" of 0 electric field in faraday cages is not a proof at all (most say the $E$ field has to be zero otherwise you'd get a non-zero $\int \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s}$ for closed paths through the cavity and wrapping around inside the meat of the conductor. This requires the proof that the $E$ field is 0 in the conductor. Also, this "proof" could be applied to the outside surface of the conductor where we know that the external field exists and supposedly the net $E$ field is 0 in the conductor. Therefore the closed line integral would be 0 - which also can't be true in statics

Comment: @DWade64 Those sound like interesting questions, rather than comments.